# SVM random sampling permutation for imbalanced data: class & score weighted vs non weighted

Tags: svm, monte-carlo

I have been running the dataset of 2 classes with imbalanced numbers with python.
Class one is 61, and class two is 66.
When I built up the SVM model and did the random sampling permutation (monte-carlo-permutation),
the middle of the permutated distribution matched perfectly at the chance level of 50% for non-weighted code (above picture), but it is not for class & score weighted code (below picture).
The black dotted line indicates chance level (50%) and the green dotted line indicates the actual model's score.

[image: Non-weighted result]
[image: Class & Score weighted result]

And here is related code for both situations:

```
## Code without weighted class and score
#SVC setting
svc_rbf = SVC(kernel='rbf', gamma=grid.best_params_["gamma"], C=grid.best_params_["C"])
#permutation
score, permutation_scores, pvalue = permutation_test_score(svc_rbf, HAPPE_PCA, HAPPE_target, cv=cv, n_permutations=10000, n_jobs=-1, verbose = 0)


## Code with class and score weighted
#SVC setting
svc_rbf = SVC(kernel='rbf',class_weight="balanced", gamma=grid.best_params_["gamma"], C=grid.best_params_["C"])
# permutation
score, permutation_scores, pvalue = permutation_test_score(svc_rbf, HAPPE_PCA, HAPPE_target, cv=cv, scoring='f1_weighted', n_permutations=10000, n_jobs=-1, verbose=0)
```

I used gridsearch to find the best-fitted parameter.
HAPPE_PCA is input data (EEG frequency powers) and HAPPE_target is classes of 1(n=61) and 2(n=66).
I think the weight corrected score might influence the shiting of the center for the weighted results.
However, I need expert's help to find related reference articles or relevant discussions.

Thank you for reading my question.

Regards,

---

Forgot to say that I used Leave-n-out for cross-validation (cv).

Comment: Could you make your question a little clearer and more specific? What do you want articles or references about? Are you asking if your approach is correct?

Comment: Agree.  Since SVM is for class-prediction, your question would have to focus on performance outcomes like AUC, sens, spec, accuracy, etc.   It looks like your score is a p-value from permutation testing?  Why would that be better than using leave-one-out CV or 2-fold, 3-fold CV?  You can also permute (shuffle) objects before they are assigned to the folds used - called "repartitioning".  Thus use e.g. ten 3-fold CV with 10 repartitions that change objects within folds each time.  What's the accuracy and AUC from using this?

Comment: Adrian: I need some explanation for why class & score weighted permutation does not center the chance level. If there are articles and references, it would be great for me to get them.

user0123: I used Leave-n-out CV for cross-validation and score is F1 score (for not weighted result) and F1_weighted score (for weighted result), not p-value.